# PHP datetime() returning one hour less time after including wordpress - fix?

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime

I just found out that if I call datetime() regulary it returns correct time,

but when I call it after including wordpress (`include('wp-load.php');`) the datetime() starts to return one hour less time (UTC time).

Wordpress is set to UTC+1. So how do I fix this problem?

Comment: So inspect the code in `wp-load.php` and find out what's causing this?

Comment: Well wp-load.php (not itself, something it includes) is obviously rewriting some PHP variable/settings - I would like to rewrite it back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there are timezone setting somewhere in `wp-load.php`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

You may declare timezone in your script or change timezone somewhere in included script (quess it is wordpress).